# How to start my network in CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, networkmanager

I have edited the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enpos2`:

```
BOOTPROTO="static"
IPADDR=192.168.1.105
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

I can't surf the web when I reboot. How do I start my network again?

```
systemctl restart network.service
```

The network isn't connected. Let's see the status.

```
network.service - LSB: Bring up/down networking
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/network)
       Active: active (exited) since Wed 2015-08-26 17:21:53 CST; 21s ago
      Process: 3494 ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/network stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Process: 3674 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/network start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)


Aug 26 17:21:50 localhost.localdomain network[3674]: Bringing up loopback interface:  Could not load file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo'
Aug 26 17:21:50 localhost.localdomain network[3674]: Could not load file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo'
Aug 26 17:21:50 localhost.localdomain network[3674]: Could not load file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo'
Aug 26 17:21:50 localhost.localdomain network[3674]: Could not load file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo'
Aug 26 17:21:50 localhost.localdomain network[3674]: [  OK  ]
Aug 26 17:21:53 localhost.localdomain network[3674]: Bringing up interface enp2s0:  [  OK  ]
Aug 26 17:21:53 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started LSB: Bring up/down networking.
```

Here is my `ifcfg-lo` file:

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo
DEVICE=lo
IPADDR=127.0.0.1
NETMASK=255.0.0.0
NETWORK=127.0.0.0
# If you're having problems with gated making 127.0.0.0/8 a martian,
# you can change this to something else (255.255.255.255, for example)
BROADCAST=127.255.255.255
ONBOOT=yes
NAME=loopback
```

Why can't I load it? How do I set my IP address static and make it connect to the Internet properly?

Comment: there must be a NetworkManager service. Try `service NetworkManager restart` (or) `service network-manager restart`

Comment: please read https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=7351, add "TYPE=Loopback"  to avoid "Could not load file....)

Answer (score 1):

CentOS 7 switched to `systemd` - use `systemctl restart network.service` to restart your network.

For static network settings like yours you may want to install `NetworkManager-config-server` RPM package using `yum`

Comment: It is more complicated than you think,please see my re-edited post.

Comment: Maybe the selinux labels are broken. Try `restorecon -FRv /etc/sysconfig/` and reload network.

Answer (score 0):

it cost me also lot of time but at least trying this:

```
# service NetworkManager stop
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
# chkconfig NetworkManager off
```

removed the lo error since the Manger was blocking it.

Just I still dont get internet on my fresh centos 7 installation

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you disabled NetworkManager and now your ifcfg-enp0s2 file doesn't have enough information in it.
In addition to:

```
BOOTPROTO="static"
IPADDR=192.168.1.105
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

You also need:

```
# Specify the default gateway
GATEWAY=<ip of your router>
# Bring the interface up on boot
ONBOOT=yes
# Specify your dns server
DNS1=<ip of your router>
```